# Simple Search and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, if-statement

I have a simple search in Rails:

```
def self.search(search)
# if search is not empty
if search
find(:all, :conditions => ["name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"])
# if search is empty return all
else
find(:all)
end
```

The view:

```
<% if @registries.empty? %>
Can't find the registry. Please try a differnet name.
<% else %>
<% @registries.each do |registry| %>
 ......etc.
```

How can I code it to show "Nothing Found" instead of find(:all) if it could not find a query?

I tries a few things, but nothing works. Even if I take out the else it still shows all queries if it can't find the one searching for.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you mean "not empty" you must test against that specifically. Remember in Ruby that there are only two values that evaluate as false: `false` and `nil`.

You probably intended:

```
if (search.present?)
  where("name like ?", "%#{search}%").all
else
  all
end
```

Use of the Rails 3 style `where` clause makes your methods a lot easier to understand. Using `find` with `:conditions` is the old Rails 1 and 2 style.

Comment: Didn't know that, but how do I code in to display no results with a message rather than all in the registry?

Comment: Check that your results aren't `empty?` and display a message if they are.

Comment: Ok, I got it to display nothing if a wrong search was typed in, but if a blank search is type in it still displays all. I edited the code above to add that code.